# onCharacteristicChanged() is not beeing called with BLE112

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I´m working with a `BLE112` device and my Callback-method `onCharacteristicChanged(...)` isn´t triggered on my Android App.

In my gatt.xml file, i defined this service:

```
    <service uuid="4300" advertise="true" id="entry_service">
        <description>Entry_Service</description>

       <characteristic uuid="4301" id="unlock_state">
        <description>Unlock_State</description>
            <properties read="true" write="true" notify="true"/>
            <value length="1">0</value>
                <descriptor uuid="4381">
                    <properties read="true" write="true"/>
                    <value length="1">0</value>
                </descriptor>
        </characteristic>
    </service>ode here
```

And i´m trying to enable notifications with this Code:

```
BluetoothGattService service = ble112Device.getBluetoothGatt().getService(uuidService);
BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic =  service.getCharacteristic(uuidChar);

if( !ble112Device.getBluetoothGatt().setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true)) // returns true
    Log.d("NOTIFICATION", "Setup failed.");

BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(uuidDescr); 

if(!descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE)) // returns true
    Log.d("DESCRIPTOR", "error");

else if(!mBluetoothLeService.writeDescriptor(ble112Device, descriptor)) // returns true
    Log.d("DESCRIPTOR", "write error");
```

In my Logchat, i get acknowledgements for writing the descriptor etc., but `onCharacteristicChanged(...)` is never called.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue.
You have to use the UUID:0x2902, when getting the descriptor.

```
BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(uuidDescr); //uuidDescr must be 0x2902
```

You don´t have to write your own descriptors in your gatt.xml.
Just get and write the descriptor with UUID 0x2902 of your characteristic you want to be notified.

After that, `onCharacteristicChanged()` fired properly.

The descriptor with UUID 2902 is called  [Client Characteristic Configuration descriptor](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/descriptors/Pages/DescriptorViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.descriptor.gatt.client_characteristic_configuration.xml)

Comment: how to convert "2902 " to UUID?

Answer (score 0):

In your GATT.XML file change the order of properties.

```
<properties notify="true" read="true" write="true" />
```

Comment: what do you mean? like this:

`
<service uuid="4300" advertise="true" id="entry_service">

        <description>Entry_Service</description>

       <characteristic uuid="4301" id="unlock_state">

        <description>Unlock_State</description>

            <properties write="true" read="true" notify="true"/>

            <value length="1">0</value>

                <descriptor uuid="4381">

                    <properties write="true" read="true">

                    <value length="1">0</value>

                </descriptor>

        </characteristic>

    </service>`

Comment: i tried this with no effects. I think the order is irrelevant. In Blugigas documentation it is not refered to have a speceific order of properties.

Comment: I am using the same BLE 112 mentioned above . also doing everything specified to set notification. But my onCharacteristicChanged() never invoked.